# Can a verilog module be instantiated in a VHDL module using entity instantiation?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

Is it possible to use VHDL style entity instantiation to include a Verilog module in a VHDL design?

I realize that I can accomplish this if I treat the Verilog module as a component and instantiate the component.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, can you provide an example code of how you treated the Verilog module as a component and instantiated the component? You want to ask a question that can be answered as opposed to someone offering their opinion. Provide some code and explain what you did and what error you got. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be useful to mention which tools you're interested in ... some may not offer the same level of support for this as others.

Comment: A component declaration allows an object file with a compatibility layer to be linked (elaborated) into a design model, while a component instantiation with the non-optional reserved word `entity` would require the module  be  previously analyzed (compiled) into a VHDL resource library (IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation). Verilog modules aren't VHDL library units (13. Design units and their analysis). Design libraries are an implementation defined storage facility for previously analyzed design units (13.2 Design libraries, also  see 13.5 Order of analysis).

Comment: See the discussion in the comments with the answer below: you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Grab from my collection of code:

```
module sync_fifo
#(parameter WIDTH    = 8, // width in bits
            L2DEPTH  = 4, // Log 2 Depth, 4=16 deep
            REGFLAGS = 1  // Full, empty are registered
)
(
   input                   clk,     // system clock                 
   input                   reset_n, // A-synchronous low reset/clear
   input                   enable,  // clock gating                 
   input                   clear,   // Synchronous clear            

   input                   write,   // write FIFO                   
   input       [WIDTH-1:0] wdata,   // write data                   
   input                   read,    // read FIFO                    
   output      [WIDTH-1:0] rdata,   // read data                    

   output reg              empty,   // FIFO is empty                
   output reg              full,    // FIFO is full                 
   output reg      [L2DEPTH:0] level    // Fill level                   
);

outp_fifo : sync_fifo 
generic map(
   WIDTH   => 10,  -- Byte + user + last
   L2DEPTH => 7,   -- 128 deep
   REGFLAGS=> 1
  )
port map 
(
   clk     => ACLK,                  -- system clock                 
   reset_n => ARESETN,               -- A-synchronous low reset/clear
   enable  => BIT_1 ,                -- clock gating                 
   clear   => BIT_0 ,                -- Synchronous clear            

   write   => package_byte_en,       -- write FIFO                   
   wdata   => outp_fifo_wt_data_and_meta , -- write data                   
   read    => outp_fifo_read   ,     -- read FIFO                    
   rdata   => outp_fifo_rd_data_and_meta ,     -- read data                    
   empty   => outp_fifo_empty,       -- FIFO is empty                
   full    => outp_fifo_full,        -- FIFO is full                 
   level   => open                   -- Fill level      
   );
```

---

Post edit:
And you can only do that with a competent declaration:

```
COMPONENT sync_fifo IS
  generic(
     WIDTH    : integer := 8;
     L2DEPTH  : integer := 8;
     REGFLAGS : integer := 1
  );
  PORT (
       clk    : in STD_LOGIC;         -- system clock                 
       reset_n: in STD_LOGIC;         -- A-synchronous low reset/clear
       enable : in STD_LOGIC;         -- clock gating                 
       clear  : in STD_LOGIC;         -- Synchronous clear            

       write  : in  STD_LOGIC;        -- write FIFO                   
       wdata  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- write data                   
       read   : in  STD_LOGIC;        -- read FIFO                    
       rdata  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- read data                    

       empty  : out STD_LOGIC; -- FIFO is empty                
       full   : out STD_LOGIC; -- FIFO is full                 
       level   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(L2DEPTH downto 0)  -- Fill level                   
    );
END COMPONENT;
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he meant with 'entity style declaration'. With the code you show, you will still need the component declaration in VHDL. He's probably referring to only declarating `outp_fifo : entity work.sync_fifo [...]`.

Comment: Well you can't do that. VHDL is straightjacket language so it will need to know what to connect to.

Comment: ^ and that's likely the answer to his question. Not what you write in your answer ;)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction. So the question should have been: "Can I instance a Verilog module in VHDL without using a component declaration." To Quote Babage: " I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

Comment: Thank you all very much.  It appears that the answer to my question is indeed "No you can not".  Also, I will take to heart the advice on asking better formed questions.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer seemed to be "no" 3 years ago when this was asked, I have found the answer in practice to be "yes you can", but with some caveats. I confirmed this using Mentor ModelSim and Xilinx Vivado.

I don't know if something about the LRM changed or if the tool vendors just decided to support it anyway. I'm using VHDL-2008, so I suspect the latter.

Here's an instance I have in one of my test files. VerFlopX is a Verilog module.

```
  VerFlopX8c: entity work.VerFlopX (rtl)
    generic map (SIZE => 8)  --integer:=1
    port map (
      Clk => Clk,                --in  wire
      D   => D16(15 downto 8) ,  --in  wire[(SIZE-1):0]
      Q   => Q16(15 downto 8));  --out wire[(SIZE-1):0]
```

The caveats:

- Note that architecture "rtl" is specified. This can (and probably should) be omitted. But it still works, which seems weird since Verilog modules don't have architectures.
- You cannot associate the Q output with open. ModelSim will return an error. If you change to a component instantiation, having a formal output connected to open is fine.